# php in array collect same array

Tags: php, arrays, collect

I have this array in PHP:

```
$a = [
['name'=>'salvar','type'=>'Qt','count'=>'1','price'=>'10','total'=>'7'],
['name'=>'salvar','type'=>'Qt','count'=>'1','price'=>'10','total'=>'7'],
['name'=>'salvar','type'=>'Qt','count'=>'1','price'=>'10','total'=>'7'],
['name'=>'salvar','type'=>'Qt','count'=>'1','price'=>'10','total'=>'7'],
['name'=>'salvar','type'=>'Qt','count'=>'1','price'=>'10','total'=>'7'],
['name'=>'corab' ,'type'=>'Qt','count'=>'1','price'=>'10','total'=>'7'],
['name'=>'corab' ,'type'=>'Qt','count'=>'1','price'=>'10','total'=>'7'],
['name'=>'corab' ,'type'=>'Qt','count'=>'1','price'=>'10','total'=>'7'],
['name'=>'yag' ,'type'=>'Qt','count'=>'1','price'=>'10','total'=>'7'],
];
```

I want to collect same array in one array. Can anyone help please?
i need some thing like this result

```
 [
  [
   ['name'=>'salvar','type'=>'Qt','count'=>'1','price'=>'10','total'=>'7'],
   ['name'=>'salvar','type'=>'Qt','count'=>'1','price'=>'10','total'=>'7'],
   ['name'=>'salvar','type'=>'Qt','count'=>'1','price'=>'10','total'=>'7'],
   ['name'=>'salvar','type'=>'Qt','count'=>'1','price'=>'10','total'=>'7'],
   ['name'=>'salvar','type'=>'Qt','count'=>'1','price'=>'10','total'=>'7']
  ],
  [
   ['name'=>'corab' ,'type'=>'Qt','count'=>'1','price'=>'10','total'=>'7'],
   ['name'=>'corab' ,'type'=>'Qt','count'=>'1','price'=>'10','total'=>'7'],
   ['name'=>'corab' ,'type'=>'Qt','count'=>'1','price'=>'10','total'=>'7'],
  ],
  [
   ['name'=>'yag' ,'type'=>'Qt','count'=>'1','price'=>'10','total'=>'7']
  ]
 ]
```

Comment: show us expected result. You want to remove duplicates - array_unique()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done by standard functions

```
$res = [];
foreach(array_count_values(array_map('json_encode', $a)) as $k=>$v) {
    $res[] = array_fill(0, $v, json_decode($k, true));
}
```

**[demo on eval.in](https://eval.in/901320)**

Comment: Glad to help. Good luck!